# TypeScript failed to compile - Badly attached item found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having an issue with React & TypeScript where a component loads for a brief second, then immediately fails with the error:

> [internal] TypeScript error in [internal] (undefined,undefined):
>   badly attached item found.  TSINTERNAL_ERROR

The affected code:

**App.tsx:**

```
import React, {useState, useMemo} from "react";

import MainMenu from "./MainMenu";
import Lobby from "./Lobby";

interface appComponentsInterface {
    [key: string]: React.FC
}

const APP_COMPONENTS: appComponentsInterface = {
    "MainMenu": MainMenu,
    "Lobby": Lobby
}

export default () => {
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState("MainMenu");
    const AppComponent = useMemo(() => APP_COMPONENTS[appState], [appState]);

    return (
        <AppComponent />
    )
}
```

**MainMenu.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";

const MainMenu : React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div> MainMenu </div>
    )
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Any advice would be appreciated - The error itself isn't too helpful.

Comment: Try removing node_modules, lock files and reinstall. Make sure to use only yarn or npm, not both.

Comment: @Phix Thank you, that worked perfectly.

Comment: just rebuilding the app was enough for me

Answer (score 10):

I have faced the same issue.
You probably installed nom modules and did not restart the dev server.

After installing any packages, try to restart the server(npm/yarn start)

Comment: Maybe add some explanation on _why_ a restart may be needed?

Comment: Restarting the server helped worked for me as well